# Is there a command to clear screen in SQLite3?

Tags: database, sqlite, terminal, command, command-prompt

To clear the SQLite console screen I tried `cls`, `.cls`, `cls;` and `.cls;` but no luck. Is there no `cls` command in SQLite?

Comment: "cls" is a DOS command, not a sqlite command.

Comment: Note quite - but this illudes the trick:
```
.print "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To execute `CLS` command in the SQLite3 shell you need to do this: `.shell cls`

As simple as that, `.shell args...` allows you to execute CMD commands in the SQLite3 shell.

Comment: Note that `.shell cls` is for Windows, use `.shell clear` for Unix and Linux.

Comment: In git bash, it moves the cursor to top of screen but does not clear the console.

Comment: @mallaudin that is because git bash has the same behavior as a Linux terminal so `clear` doesn't really clear the console. Try using `tput reset` or just `reset` in your git bash to actually clear the console.

Answer (score 31):

There is no `clear` command in the SQLite command-line client.

But, if you're on a unix-based system (includes Mac OS X) you can use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

**Update:**
While my answer is quick and simple, if you're on a compatible OS, make sure you also check out [ivan0590's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25217935/8554766) about the `.shell` command. Definitely a "good to know" as well.

Comment: Here is a [thread on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434240/ctrll-in-terminal), explaining what `Ctrl+l` does, and why.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the shell.
In Ubuntu -> `.shell clear`

Answer (score 6):

On mac or Unix Operating systems:

```
   .shell clear
```

or:

```
   .shell reset
```

Answer (score 5):

**.shell cls** will always work(C'mon, if you are in windows). If you are using Linux/Unix/Mac OS, try using **.shell clear**

Answer (score 5):

For **Windows**:

```
.shell cls
```

For **Linux** and **Mac**:

```
.shell clear
```